# what is being done here [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]

Tags: bash

In RHEL6 /etc/profile near the end there's an if statement:

```
if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ];
```

The `!=` I'm guessing is the "not equal" for strings comparison operator.  The left side I'm guessing is the string within the variable `-@*i` and the right side is the string within `$-` (which I think are the flags passed to the script).  This is in the middle of a for loop and $i should exist however I don't know what `-#*i` might possibly be.

Assuming I'm correct that `$-` are flags passed to the script, I'm thinking `${-#*i}` must also be flags but I don't really have a clue.

Can someone please explain.  Links with list of these special variables would be appreciated too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gotta love uncommented script! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the `$-` variable is, but the above code is basically testing whether `$-` contains an `i`.

In bash `${var#pattern}` means `$var` with the smallest matching `pattern` removed. If `pattern` is not found then `$var` is returned unchanged.

So in your example, if `$-` was `fish`. Then `${-#*i}` would be `sh`. So the if statement would be true (because `sh` != `fish`).

Links for you:

Variable expansion in bash: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Bash Defined variables: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Variables

Comment: You might find [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f) and [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) to contain useful information. I doubt that `$-` would ever contain "fish".

Answer (score 4):

Look in the bash manpage for "${parameter#word}". # in the left expression removes the pattern "*i" which is "from start to 'i'" of the contents of $-. $- contains the current shell's flags (see `set`).

kjp is right that it is a check if the shell is run in interactive mode (by removing a possible "i" flag from the string for comparison). Bash's manpage says:

*An  interactive  shell  is one started without non-option arguments and without the -c option whose standard input and error are both connected to terminals (as determined by isatty(3)), or one  started  with  the  -i option.   PS1  is set and $- includes i if bash is interactive, allowing a shell script or a startup file to test this state.*

Comment: `$-` are the current flags, not shell parameters, which is `$@`.

Answer (score 4):

It is checking if the current shell is an interactive shell or not.

Presence of `-i` in the `$-` variable (which contains the list of flags passed to the shell) is [one way of checking for interactive vs non-interactive shell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html#IITEST). See [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) for a list of internal shell variables including `$-`